# jsreport, dynamic number of charts through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, jsreport

I'm using `JSreport 3.4.1.` and `Chart.js 3.8.0`. From a server API I'm getting a series of data to create n. charts. The problem is that the number of charts are never the same (they depend on various parameters in a database).

I cannot create n. static charts for the reason above, so I was trying to dynamically create and inject them in the DOM through jQuery, but I'm having some difficulties:

It successfully creates the first chart, but with incorrect data (like it isn't waiting for the trigger input), and the second chart isn't shown at all.

[image]

Any idea on how to create a dynamic number of charts based on the number of objects (inside an array) that arrives through an API?

```js
const datasets = {
  "datasets": [{
      "dynamic_id": 0,
      "NomeAnomalia": "MIT Appoggi",
      "GruppiAnomalie": 199,
      "anomalyList": [{
        "GruppiAnomalie": 199,
        "Code": "Classe 1\nApp1",
        "Name": "Piastra di base deformata",
        "Class": "Classe 1",
        "Severity": "0 - Lieve",
        "Value": 100
      }],
      "pieChartData": [{
          "severityName": "Lieve",
          "severityValue": 100
        },
        {
          "severityName": "Media",
          "severityValue": 0
        },
        {
          "severityName": "Forte",
          "severityValue": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dynamic_id": 1,
      "NomeAnomalia": "MIT Impalcati,Travi,Traversi CA CAP",
      "GruppiAnomalie": 199,
      "anomalyList": [{
        "GruppiAnomalie": 199,
        "Code": "Classe 1\nApp1",
        "Name": "Piastra di base deformata",
        "Class": "Classe 1",
        "Severity": "0 - Lieve",
        "Value": 100
      }],
      "pieChartData": [{
          "severityName": "Lieve",
          "severityValue": 100
        },
        {
          "severityName": "Media",
          "severityValue": 0
        },
        {
          "severityName": "Forte",
          "severityValue": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
var content = document.getElementById('content');

for (dataset of datasets.datasets) {
  var divPieChart = `
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="chart-container">
          <canvas id="bar_chart_${dataset.dynamic_id}"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`;

  content.innerHTML += divPieChart;

  var bar_chart_ctx = document.getElementById(`bar_chart_${dataset.dynamic_id}`).getContext('2d');
  var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_chart_ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [1, 2, 3],
      datasets: [{
        "label": "2017",
        "data": [5, 3, 7.5],
        "backgroundColor": ["rgba(215, 221, 234)"]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      devicePixelRatio: 1.5,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: "top"
        }
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      },
      animation: {
        onComplete: function() {
          // set the PDF printing trigger when the animation is done
          // to have this working, the chrome-pdf menu in the left must
          // have the wait for printing trigger option selected
          window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

I've set a playground with mock data (not really needed cause I've put static data inside the charts) so you can see what I mean:
[playground test](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/alesssz/ZlQ6NSw_)

Thank you

EDIT 
I figured out how to do it (JSReport specifically): in JSReport, `window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true` tells the report that all the components in the page are done to print. Breaking down the "creation" of the html and the "creation" of the charts into two separates loop, using the length of the dataset as control, makes the work (only JSReport, I won't post a snippet cause it won't work the same as `window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true` is not present). 
Here's the playground if someone needs it: [playground test](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/alesssz/%7E0oMgXoM)

Comment: I've created a snippet in your question from the off-site data, where it appears to work fine. The only issue I could see what that `dataset of datasets` needs to be `dataset of datasets.datasets`, as the array is a property within the datasets variable - although I'm not sure if this is an implementation problem due to the above sample not using AJAX. Worth testing on your end. You should have had a big red error in the console if this was the case.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for your comment. In fact, `dataset of datasets` is right...the mock data (if you see the playground link) is injected to the report that way, so in `datasets` you can find the 2 object. But that's not the problem right now....Inside the loop I expect 2 executions, so 2 canvas, but it appears that only one is showing (in your edit too). Plus, this is made inside jsreport, so the `window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true` is mandatory and it's not working either

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Chart.js - it only allows 1 chart to be shown per page. I slowed down your loop using a timeout and you can see the behaviour here. The first chart is rendered, then the second iteration occurs 2 seconds later - the first chart is removed and the second appears: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jnreLqms/. I'd suggest raising this issue with the Chart.js devs, or finding a different library which better supports multiple charts per page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hey, thank you for your answers, I figured out how to do it specifically in JSReport....I didn't post a snippet 'cause it won't work the same, JSReport has some specific commands that will not work outside of it. I post a playground if you wanna check